# How can I determine the rating of an unmarked dual-pole circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I would like to install a new electric cooktop. The panel has a dual-pole breaker serving the current electric cooktop but there is NO marking on the breaker to indicate the rating. The new cooktop requires 60A. Is there a way to determine the rating on that circuit currently without hiring an electrician?

Comment: The rating of the existing breaker doesn't matter as much as the size of the wires unless you're certain that the breaker is sized appropriately for the wiring. You can purchase an AWG measuring gauge to measure the wire size (note that many of the measuring gauges you'll find online measure SWG not AWG), or less accurately, purchase a few short lengths of wire of various gauges and compare them. Breakers (for most panels) are not that expensive, I'd replace the breaker with a new one if it really is completely unmarked.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you mean there is no marking on the handle or front of the breaker (since that is all you see with the electric panel cover still on).

If that is the case, there should be at least a part number on the side of the breaker, which can be looked up online if the rating isn't part of the part number.

But you will have to turn off the power, unscrew the panel cover, and pull out the breaker to see it. Only do this if you are comfortable installing and removing breakers.  If you aren't sure you know how to do it safely, call an electrician.